# Error al acceder a mi sitio web

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Estoy tratando de publicar un sitio web con el servidor XAMPP v5.6.8. Ya configure un virtual host para poder acceder de forma local al sitio. El sitio esta alojado en un disco duro externo.

---

Al archivo host ubicado en `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\` le añadí la linea

```
127.0.0.1 misitio.com
```

---

Y el archivo httpd-vhosts.conf quedo asi :

```
NameVirtualHost *:8000
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "E:\Programas\xampp\htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8000>
  DocumentRoot "K:\Proyectos\misitio.com"
  ServerName misitio.com
  <Directory "K:\Proyectos\misitio.com">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Sin embargo al acceder desde el navegador me sale el error

> Network Access Message: The website cannot be found

---

Según tengo entendido esto es suficiente para publicar el sitio que igual no lo encuentra.

Comment: Solo para descartar, qué estás colocando en el url para acceder al sitio?

Comment: Estoy poniendo misitio.com/

Comment: me parece que debes colocar misitio.com:8000 ya que estás indicando ese puerto en la configuración, de lo contrario modifica la misma colocando :80 así no tendrás que colocar el puerto cuando indiques misitio.com